# Rails set db table values to nil

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have huge db, and in one table i want to set somefield to nil, how can i do this? When i do like that:

```
@act = Article.all
 @act.each do |aaa|
   aaa.name = nil
 end
```

But this loads system, how to do this in more faster and better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
Article.update_all(:name => nil)
```

This will go directly to the database, without loading the objects.